# taskkill: The process not found

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe, kill

This happens from time to time: I run a simple taskkill command (as administrator) like this:

```
taskkill /im sidebar.exe /f
```

But get the following:

```
ERROR: The process "sidebar.exe" not found.
```

Also tried without ".exe". I see the process in Task Manager:

[image]

Killing the process from Task Manager works.

I suspect it happens when the process appears stuck (because that's when I kill it), but it's still strange and inconsistent.

I run Windows 7 Professional SP1 64bit.

Comment: Try the command as this `taskkill /F /IM sidebar.exe /T`

Comment: It's a rare problem I can't really recreate, I just wait for it to happen. Will update.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use tasklist to get the PID of sidebar and taskkill /PID

```
> tasklist |find /i "sidebar"
sidebar.exe                  17252 Console                    1       209.680 K

> for /f "tokens=2" %A in ('tasklist ^|find /i "sidebar"') Do @Echo PID=%A
PID=17252

> for /f "tokens=2" %A in ('tasklist ^|find /i "sidebar"') Do @Taskkill /PID %A
```